# Change color of text during runtime (Unity)?

Tags: colors, unity-game-engine, runtime

I have a **GameObject** embedded inside my Canvas that has a "**Text (Script)**" Component. I wish to alter the `color.a` attribute during runtime of that element. Does anybody have an idea of how to do it? I can't seem to access it with any `GetComponent<Type> ()` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if you want to change R,G,B or A components of the color of the text you can do it this way:

```css
Public Text text;
float r=0.2f,g=0.3f,b=0.7f,a=0.6f;

void Start()
{
  text=gameobject.GetComponent<Text>();
  text.color= new Color(r,g,b,a);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code:  <br/>  m_TextGreen.color = Color.green; //This did work
          <br/>   m_TextGreen.color = new Color(135, 245, 15, 255); // This did not work

Answer (score 4):

```
public Text myText;
```

> Attach this to the UI component of text in Hierarchy

```
myText.color = Color.green;
myText.text = "Enter anything, will display in UI Text";
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have to assign new Color to text.color. You can make your own color to assign or use one of the standard colors:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

public Text text;

void Start () 

    {
       text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ();
       text.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CrossFadeAlpha](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.CrossFadeAlpha.html). See link for usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use color attribute to provide color for the text.

It can be done by two ways -> using the color static attributes and color class constructor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ColorDemo : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Text infoText;

    void Start () {
       infoText.text = "Hello World";
       infoText.color = Color.red; //Red color using Color class
       //Red color using hex value. (255,0,0) => 255/255, 0/255, 0/255) => (1,0,0)
       infoText.color = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f); 
       // Color with opacity value. 1 means opaque and 0 means transparent.
       infoText.color = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f); 
    }
}
```